# Database Connection is Not Ending

Tags: vb.net, database-connection

I have the following code to insert some data from a `GridView` to a oracle database.

```
Protected Sub btnInsert_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnInsert.Click
        Dim con = New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml2; User ID=sfpl; Password=a; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle")
        con.Open()
        For Each gvRow As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim trndate As Date = ddlTrnDte.SelectedValue
            Dim ZoneNo As Integer = ddlZone.SelectedValue
            Dim DocNo As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtDocNo"), TextBox)
            Dim VehCod As DropDownList = CType(gvRow.FindControl("ddlVeh"), DropDownList)
            Dim CircleNo As DropDownList = CType(gvRow.FindControl("ddlCircle"), DropDownList)
            Dim Contractor As DropDownList = CType(gvRow.FindControl("ddlContractor"), DropDownList)
            Dim Supplier As DropDownList = CType(gvRow.FindControl("ddlSupplier"), DropDownList)
            Dim NetWt As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtNetWt"), TextBox)
            Dim Rate As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtRate"), TextBox)
            Dim SNF As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtSNF"), TextBox)
            Dim FAT As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtFAT"), TextBox)
            Dim LR As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtLR"), TextBox)
            Dim TS As TextBox = CType(gvRow.FindControl("txtTS"), TextBox)
            'Create Connection


            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("Insert into MLK_02_01 (TRN_DTE,ZONE_NO,CIRCLE_NO,CNT_NO,DOC_NO,SUP_COD,VEH_NUM,NET_WEIGHT,Q_SNF,Q_FAT,Q_LR,Q_TS,RATE,veh_cod) VALUES (:TRN_DTE,:ZONE_NO,:CIRCLE_NO,:CNT_NO,:DOC_NO,:SUP_COD,:VEH_NUM,:NET_WEIGHT,:Q_SNF,:Q_FAT,:Q_LR,:Q_TS,:RATE,:veh_cod)", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            'TrnDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add(":trn_dte", (OleDb.OleDbType.Date))
            cmd.Parameters(":trn_dte").Value = DateTime.Now()
            cmd.Parameters(":trn_dte").Value = ddlTrnDte.SelectedValue
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ZONE_no", ZoneNo)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":CIRCLE_no", CircleNo.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":CNT_no", Contractor.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Doc_No", DocNo.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":sup_cod", Contractor.SelectedValue)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Veh_num", VehCod.SelectedItem.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":NET_WEIGHT", NetWt.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Q_SNF", SNF.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Q_FAT", FAT.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Q_LR", LR.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":Q_TS", TS.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":rate", Rate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":veh_cod", VehCod.SelectedValue)


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Label1.Text = "All Records are Saved Successfully"
            con.Close()
            btnInsert.Enabled = False
        Next

    End Sub
```

Data is inserted into database fine but when the form is closed the database connection does not end. I need help in ending the database session to eliminate further communication errors.

Comment: Is there any One Knows the Answer to My Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention it's a page, so I'm assuming this is an ASP page.

IIS has database connection pooling enabled by default. This means that even though your code closed your connection, IIS maintains a connection in order to make the next query from the next request execute faster.

To disable connection pooling, in your database connection string add this:

> Pooling=false

```
New OleDbConnection("Data Source=sml2; User ID=sfpl; Password=a; provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle; Pooling=false")
```

Also, after your execute change to this:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
```

After the con.Close():

```
con.Close()
con.Dispose()
```

and that should dispose the command and connection objects.

Comment: Sir Its Still Doing Same Thing that when each time i Press Insert Button then it Make anothere session with Db.

Comment: Instead of using [con.Close()], try using [con.Dispose()]

Comment: Sir Situation is same On Each Hit On Insert Button It is Making connection with DB.Sir Anything Wrong Else

Comment: As far as I know, those are the only two things that would potentially keep a database connection opened. If that didn't do the trick, hopefully someone else will know what else to try. Good luck

Comment: Make sure you also Dispose of your command object.  Your command object holds a reference to the connection as well.